# Why this group Hide/Show code didn't work?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checkbox, groupbox

I want to write codes that when checkbox is clicked, the hidden group box is shown, and then do the simple calculations. 
Here are my codes:

```
Public Class frmMenu
    Private Sub btnCompute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click
        Dim Burgers, Fries, Drinks, sum As Double
        If chkBurgers.Checked Then
            grpBurgers.Visible = True
            If radRegular.Checked Then
                Burgers = 4.19
            ElseIf radWcheese.Checked Then
                Burgers = 4.79
            ElseIf radWbacon.Checked Then
                Burgers = 4.79
            ElseIf radWbcheese.Checked Then
                Burgers = 5.39
            End If
        End If
        If chkFries.Checked Then
            grpFries.Visible = True
            If radSmall.Checked Then
                Fries = 2.39
            ElseIf radMedium.Checked Then
                Fries = 3.09
            ElseIf radLarge.Checked Then
                Fries = 4.99
            End If
        End If
        If chkDrinks.Checked Then
            grpDrinks.Visible = True
            If radSoda.Checked Then
                Drinks = 1.69
            ElseIf radBottled.Checked Then
                Drinks = 1.49
            End If
        End If
        sum = Burgers + Fries + Drinks
        txtCost.Text = sum.ToString("C")
    End Sub
End Class
```

I use

```
If chkBurgers.Checked Then
    grpBurgers.Visible = True
```

to show hidden group box, but it did not work in `VB 2012`, what's wrong with my code? It seems pretty to me.

Comment: Do you want the hidden groups to show as soon as you check the box?

Comment: Is the group box inside something else that is not visible?  `when checkbox is clicked`: you want to use the CheckedChanged event of the CheckBox for that.

Comment: @user3510227 Exactly, yes, I want to show hidden groups as soon as I check the box.

Comment: @LarsTech Sir, can you write that as an answer?

Comment: You'll need another event handler for your checkboxes then. Right now it looks like you're only checking if they're ticked when the user presses the button bound to the event handler given above.

Comment: @user3510227 I really don't know how to do that, would you mind write that as an answer?

Comment: click on the checkbox and VB will create the CheckChanged event for you; put your code there to toggle the groupbox (usually better to just disable it though)

Comment: the dropdowns at the top of the code editor have all the other events for all the other controls.  select the control on the left, then the desired event from the right drop down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are managing the visibility on button press, which should instead be done on checking the checkboxes. I would have proceeded as the below;

```
Public Class frmMenu

Private Burgers, Fries, Drinks, sum As Double

Private Sub chkBurgers_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkBurgers.CheckedChanged


       grpBurgers.Visible = chkBurgers.Checked 
       If chkBurgers.Checked then
        Select case True
         Case radRegular.Checked 
                Burgers = 4.19
         Case radWcheese.Checked  
                Burgers = 4.79
         Case radWbacon.Checked  
                Burgers = 4.79
         Case radWbcheese.Checked  
                Burgers = 5.39
         Case else
                Burgers = 0.00
       End Case

      End If
End Sub

Private Sub chkFries_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkFries.CheckedChanged

       grpFries.Visible = chkFries.Checked
       If chkFries.Checked then
        Select case True
         Case radSmall.Checked 
                Fries = 2.39
         Case radMedium.Checked  
                Fries = 3.09
         Case radLarge.Checked  
                Fries = 4.99
         Case else
                Fries = 0.00
       End Case

      End If
 End Sub

 Private Sub chkDrinks_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkDrinks.CheckedChanged

      grpDrinks.Visible = chkDrinks.Checked 
       If chkDrinks.Checked then
        Select case True
         Case radSoda.Checked
                Drinks = 1.69
         Case radBottled.Checked  
                Drinks = 1.49 
         Case else
                Fries = 0.00
       End Case

      End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnCompute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click

      sum = Burgers + Fries + Drinks
      txtCost.Text = sum.ToString("C")

End Sub

End Class
```